# How to save API response in database?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create an app with flutter that calls a Restful API and when the status code is 200 saves the response which is user information in a sqlite database.

I don't know how call API and save it in database so what can I do? Can somebody help me?

Comment: Try https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-get-data-from-a-rest-api-and-save-locally-in-a-sqlite-database-9a9de5867939

Comment: i think it's not difficult

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple
Your answer has **two steps**

**Step 1: Call api**

For this step, you can use the http package implemented for Flutter
Examples of http package codes can be seen from this link
https://pub.dev/packages/http/example

**Step 2: Saving the response in the local database**

For this step, you can also use the shared preference package, the sample code of which is available in the link below
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences/example

I hope it was useful

Answer (score 0):

**To complete this task you need two packages from [Pub.dev](https://pub.dev)**

- Ready api get request : will return the data to store into the database
- [HTTP](https://pub.dev/packages/http) : This package contains a set of high-level functions and classes that make it easy to consume HTTP resources. It's multi-platform, and supports mobile, desktop, and the browser.
- [SQFLITE](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) : SQLite plugin for Flutter. Supports iOS, Android and MacOS.

**how to do it ?**

you can do it in 4 steps :

- Create the databse
- Call the resource from http.get request
- Format the data as you want to save it using json or string
- Save the data to the sqfdatabase

---

```
 var url =
      Uri.https('www.yourApiLink.com', '/directory/expl/item', {'q': '{http}'});

  // Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted response.
  var response = await http.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonResponse =
        convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    var itemCount = jsonResponse['totalItems'];
    String response_str = jsonResponse.toString();
    
// Insert some records in a transaction
await database.transaction((txn) async {
  int id1 = await txn.rawInsert(
      'INSERT INTO Test(name, value, num) VALUES("some name", 1234, 456.789)');
  print('inserted1: $id1');
  int id2 = await txn.rawInsert(
      'INSERT INTO Test(name, value, num) VALUES(?, ?)',
      ['response', $response_str]);
  
});

  } else {
    print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
  }
```

**You need first to do this for sqflite**

```
// Get a location using getDatabasesPath
var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
String path = join(databasesPath, 'demo.db');


// open the database
Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
    onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
  // When creating the db, create the table
  await db.execute(
      'CREATE TABLE Test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, value INTEGER, num REAL)');
});
```

> Note : This is not a copy paste answer you have to adapt it to your
> problem